# Asymptotic bounds and Big Θ notation

Tags: complexity-theory

Suppose that f(n)=4^n and g(n)=n^n, will it be right to conclude that f(n)=Θ(g(n)).

In my opinion it's a correct claim but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Check out my answer, accepted answer is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is incorrect. f(n) = Theta(g(n)) if and only if both f(n) = O(g(n)) and g(n) = O(f(n)). It is true that f(n) = O(g(n)). We will show that it is not the case that g(n) = O(f(n)).

Assume g(n) = O(f(n)). Then there exists a positive real constant c and a positive natural number n0 such that for all n > n0, g(n) <= c * f(n). For our functions, this implies n^n <= c * 4^n. If we take the nth root of both sides of this inequality we get n <= 4c^(1/n). We are free to assume c >= 1 and n0 >= since if we found a smaller value that worked a larger value would work too. For all c > 1 and n > 1, 4c^(1/n) is strictly less than 4c. But then if we choose n > 4c, the inequality is false. So, there cannot be an n0 such that for all n at least n0 the condition holds. This is a contradiction; our initial assumption is disproven.